# Minimize / Iconify JavaFX undecorated stage on Ubuntu not working

Tags: linux, javafx, gtk

I've created small library containing a custom window/stage to use for all my applications to have a constant and uniform look.
Basically it's just a undecorated stage with a AnchorPane which contains the customized *Minimize*/*Maximize*/*Close* and *Resize* controls.

The only problem is the method which is performed when the *Minimize* button is pressed. Nothing happens when running the app on my main system (Arch Linux), it looks like the application is frozen, here's a visual example:
[Example image uploaded on Imgur, haven't got enough reps yet to post images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx80F.gif)

Minimize method code:

```
void minimizeWindow() {
  window.setIconified(true);
}
```

On `Windows 7 x64` everything works fine, the application gets iconified and also can be enlarged again.

I think this is a bug in JavaFX itself or a compatibility problem with GTK3.
Someone know how to fix this problem or got a workaround for this until this officially gets fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. This has already been fixed but there are few related left-overs jiras and this fix will be most-probably released with Java 9.

*The release may be pushed forward, depending on the fix of the other related bugs.*

You can view the details and follow up the same here :

[[Linux] Stage.setIconified(true) not working with TRANSPARENT or UNDECORATED stage](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095451)